# High-energy-astrophysics vs. particles and other tags in the same field

Tags: discussion, tags

This a follow-up discussion to [high-energy-astrophysics tag usage guideline, could this be improved?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/)

There are currently (February 17th, 2021) only 9 questions tagged [particles](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particles), compared 22 questions tagged [high-energy-astrophysics](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-energy-astrophysics), 26 [neutrinos](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neutrinos), and 33 [nucleosynthesis](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nucleosynthesis).

1. Many physicists I know use "high-energy-physics" and "(elementary) particle physics" synonymously, so should we introduce a synonym?
2. In my mind [neutrinos](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neutrinos) implies [particles](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particles) and [high-energy-physics](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-energy-physics), but not the other way round. Is that a potential problem that users might get confused which tag to use, if there are tags of different abstraction-levels (parent-tag "particles", child-tag "neutrino")?

Comment: I'm going to leave #1 to others to discuss, but thought it was worth mentioning in regards to #2 that having different levels of abstraction is a good thing. If people get confused, we can just fix the tags on their question for them. Often it's helpful to put both the higher-level and lower-level tag on a question if there's room for it. If you run out of room, stick with just the most specific ones to the question.